# Disable scrolling but capture scrolling data with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to prevent default scrolling behavior while still determining the number of pixels a user has attempted to scroll.

My objective is (at some vertical position on my page) to fix a navigation element to the top of the screen and hijack the scroll/swipe event to pull down a mobile menu when the user scrolls back up (so moving said element up and down by *n* pixels depending on how many pixels the user tries to scroll).

I am aware of the UX/accessibility concerns insofar as blocking native behavior, but the suits want what the suits want.

So far I have:

```
$('body').on({
 'mousewheel' : function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    e.stopPropagation();
 }
});
```

but am stumped as to how to access the number of pixels scrolled (since element/scroll offsets are no longer a guide).

Edit: Please note that this question is specifically asking for information regarding mouse/scroll actions while scrolling is blocked. Don't think this has been appropriately marked as duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable scrolling temporarily?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)

Comment: use jquery swipe event

Comment: @suvroc I don't think it's a duplicate, that post doesn't provide any information about capturing scrolled pixels while scrolling is disabled.

Comment: need an example... why not just move on each `mousewheel` for some pixels? its fired for each scroll step. should be fine.

Comment: @befzz if you know how to do that, please provide an answer. I know how to track the movement of the body, but if I'm cancelling the propagation of mousewheel (to stop the page from scrolling) I have no idea how to get the information about how many pixels the user has scrolled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is browser-depended because of the `mousewheel` event you are using. This is because it is [non-standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousewheel). Don't use it!

In Chrome (43.0) you get different properties with different values:

```
e.originalEvent.wheelDelta: -120
e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY: -120
e.originalEvent.deltaY: 100
```

In IE (11.0), you can get only one property:

```
e.originalEvent.wheelDelta: -120
```

In Firefox (38.0.5), the capturing of the mousewheel event doesn't work at all.

**Solution:**
Use the `wheel` event ([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel)). This event has the `e.originalEvent.deltaY` property in all browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Before cancelling event propagation take the deltaY out of the original event like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mndLvacn/)

```
$('body').on({
  'wheel' : function(e) {
      console.log(e.originalEvent.deltaY);
      e.preventDefault(); 
      e.stopPropagation();
 }
});
```

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Did you use Chrome as browser?

Comment: As per documentation it should be supported in IE 9+ and FF. For more details about cross browser compatibility [see here ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/wheel)

Comment: There is a difference between the `wheel` and `mousewheel` events, see my answer.